# Spring Boot: properties class is "usable" in @SpringBootApplication class, but NULL everywhere else

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a separate class for Spring Boot specific application.properties defined:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "clearing.alertfile")
public class ClearingAlertFileProperties {

    private String folder;

    public String getFolder () {
        return folder;
    }

    public void setFolder (String folder) {
        this.folder = folder;
    }
}
```

When I instantiate above class in a @SpringBootApplication class, it is working as expected.

But when I try to instantiate the ClearingAlertFileProperties class in another class, the instance of ClearingAlertFileProperties is NULL.

```
@Component
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "repgen.fileparser")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ClearingFileParser implements FileParser {

    private int fileParsedYearValue;
    private int fileParsedMonthValue;
    private int fileParsedDayValue;
    private int fileParsedHoursValue;
    private int fileParsedMinutesValue;
    private int fileParsedSecondsValue;
    private int fileParsedModuleValue;
    private int fileParsedStatusValue;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClearingFileParser.class);

    @Autowired
    ClearingAlertFileProperties clearingAlertFileProperties;

    @Override
    public void parse (String file) throws IOException {

        String clearingFileFolder = clearingAlertFileProperties.getFolder();
        String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(clearingFileFolder + file)));

        log.info("Parsing clearing.alert file:" + file + ". File inner length: " + contents.length());
        log.info("Location of file: " + clearingFileFolder);

    ....
    }
```

I have also tried using @Autowired Environment solution, but that also returned same NULL. There seems to be a problem with my spring boot annotation config, but   I couldn't figure out which one. Thanks!

**EDIT**:

**Application class**:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"corepackage.com.repgen.*","mainpackage.config"})
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    private static final String OUTDESTSAMPLE = "deniss@com.com";
    private static final String CLIENTIDSAMPLE = "756";

    @Autowired
    private ClearingAlertFileProperties clearingAlertFileProperties;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(DBReportRepository DBReportRepository)
    {
        ClearingFileParser clearingFileParser = new ClearingFileParser();

        return args -> {

            clearingFileParser.parse("pos_clearing.alert");
            ClearingFileModel clearingFileModel = clearingFileParser.getClearingFileData();

            log.info("Got date from clearing file: " + clearingFileModel.getDay());
        };
    }
}
```

**ClearingAlertFileProperties class:**

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "clearing.alertfile")
public class ClearingAlertFileProperties {

    private String folder;

    public String getFolder () {
        return folder;
    }

    public void setFolder (String folder) {
        this.folder = folder;
    }
}
```

**FileParser interface**:

```
interface FileParser {

    void parse(String file) throws IOException;
}
```

**ClearingFileParser class**:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ClearingFileParser implements FileParser {

    private int fileParsedYearValue;
    private int fileParsedMonthValue;
    private int fileParsedDayValue;
    private int fileParsedHoursValue;
    private int fileParsedMinutesValue;
    private int fileParsedSecondsValue;
    private int fileParsedModuleValue;
    private int fileParsedStatusValue;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClearingFileParser.class);

    @Autowired
    ClearingAlertFileProperties clearingAlertFileProperties;

    @Override
    public void parse (String file) throws IOException {
        clearingFileFolder = clearingAlertFileProperties.getFolder();
        String clearingFileFolder = clearingAlertFileProperties.getFolder();
        String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(clearingFileFolder + file)));
        fileParsedYearValue = Integer.parseInt(contents.substring(0,5));

        ....
    }

    public ClearingFileModel getClearingFileData() {
        ClearingFileModel clearingFileModel = new ClearingFileModel();
        ....

        return clearingFileModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating/accessing the `ClearingFileParser` instance?

Comment: By creating an instance in the @SpringBootApplication class like this:  atBean
 public CommandLineRunner app(ClientRepository ClientRepository)
 {

  ClearingFileParser clearingFileParser = new ClearingFileParser();

Comment: where does your ClearingAlertFileProperties reside, which package?

Comment: @DenissM.That's the problem, then. For `ClearingAlertFileProperties` to be injected, you need to let Spring create the `ClearingFileProperties` instance for you. It looks like `ClearingFileProperties` will already be a bean so you could either have it injected or look it up from the application context manually.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson i'm new to spring-boot, how would I let spring inject my properties file?

Comment: @kuhajeyan mainpackage.config

Comment: @DennisM If you share a complete example I'll be able to point you in the right direction

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, I have edited my post above. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I 'manually' created an instance of ClearingFileParser and Spring wasn't aware of this. The fix is very simple:

**ClearingFileParser.java** :

```
@Service
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.package.repgen.*"})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ClearingFileParser implements FileParser {

    private int fileParsedYearValue;
    ...

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClearingFileParser.class);

    @Autowired
    private ClearingAlertFileProperties clearingAlertFileProperties;

    @Override
    public void parse (String file) throws IOException {
        String clearingFileFolder = clearingAlertFileProperties.getFolder();
        String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(clearingFileFolder + file)));
        ...
    }

    public ClearingFileModel getClearingFileData() {
        ClearingFileModel clearingFileModel = new ClearingFileModel();
        clearingFileModel.setYear(fileParsedYearValue);
        ...

        return clearingFileModel;
    }
}
```

Notice @Service added.

**Application.java :**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(DBReportRepository DBReportRepository, ClearingFileParser clearingFileParser)
    {
        return args -> {

            clearingFileParser.parse("clearing.alert");
            ClearingFileModel clearingFileModel = clearingFileParser.getClearingFileData();
...
```

Notice that ClearingFileParser was instantiated in the CommandLineRunner.

Answer (score 0):

seems spring cannot find your ClearingAlertFileProperties (since it resides in another package ) , Move your

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"repgen.fileparser","mainpackage.config"})
```

(include package "mainpackage.config")

to Application class that is annotated with @SpringBootApplication class or the configuration class

Comment: This doesn't work. It throws an error related to that it cannot load any application.properties data. org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]...

Comment: If I modify your code like this: @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"repgen.*","mainpackage.config"}) then there is no exception thrown, but the autowiring still doesn't work.